# Change hamburger icon

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change my hamburger icon to go to X. What i want to create is the top and bottom lines to go to the middle and then to go X. This is my code so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".icon").click(function() {
    $(".icon").toggleClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #ff5c40;
}

.icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  Left: 50%;
  transform: transition(-50%, -50%);
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

.hamburger {
  width: 50px;
  height: 6px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  transition: .5s;
}

.hamburger:before,
.hamburger:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 6px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  transition: .5s;
}

.hamburger:after {
  top: 16px;
}

.hamburger:before {
  top: -16px;
}

.icon.active .hamburger {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.icon.active .hamburger:before {
   top: 0px;
     -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg) ;
     transform:  rotate(-135deg);
     -webkit-transition: top .2s ease-in-out,  -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out .2s;
     transition: top .2s ease-in-out,  -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out .2s;
     transition: top .2s ease-in-out,  transform .3s ease-in-out .2s;
     transition: top .2s ease-in-out,  transform .3s ease-in-out .2s,  -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out .2s;
}



.icon.active .hamburger:after {
  top: 0px;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) ;
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
      transition: top .2s ease-in-out,  -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out .2s;
      transition: top .2s ease-in-out,  transform .3s ease-in-out .2s;
      transition: top .2s ease-in-out,  transform .3s ease-in-out .2s,  -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out .2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="icon">
  <div class="hamburger">
  </div>
</div>
```

I really appreciate it if anyone would help me. Since I've been stuck in this for so long, it have been three or four days now. and i don't know what else to do!!

Comment: I changed my code a little bit so i got what i want it :)

Answer (score 3):

How about rotating your other line -45 deg?

EDIT: updated per your request via comments. This now uses keyframes.  We say at 0% of the total time do nothing, then at 50% of the total time (1second of 2 total) bring the top and bottom line together in the middle. 
 Then at 100% of total time(at 2seconds)rotate our lines to make a X. You could also look into chaining animations but i find it kind of unreliable. this solution, takes your work and splits it into what you want to happen The `forwards` will keep the last frame of the animation, giving you the X look rather than repeating the animation over and over.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".icon").click(function() {
    $(".icon").toggleClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #ff5c40;
}

.icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  Left: 50%;
  transform: transition(-50%, -50%);
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

.hamburger {
  width: 50px;
  height: 6px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  transition: .5s;
}

.hamburger:before,
.hamburger:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 6px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  transition: .5s;
}

.hamburger:after {
  top: 16px;
}

.hamburger:before {
  top: -16px;
}

.icon.active .hamburger {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.icon.active .hamburger:before {
  animation: makeXLeft 2s forwards;
}

.icon.active .hamburger:after {
    animation: makeXRight 2s forwards;
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes makeXLeft {
  0% {}
  50% {top: 0px;transform: rotate(0deg);}
  100% {top: 0px;transform: rotate(45deg);}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes makeXRight {
  0% {}
  50% {top: 0px;transform: rotate(0deg);}
  100% {top: 0px;transform: rotate(-45deg);}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="icon">
  <div class="hamburger">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want them to go to the middle just like the last line does, and then from where to go to X

Comment: Hmm I am not understanding can you try to explain in another way please?

Comment: @ella your comment is not at all clear, this answer works perfectly.

Comment: if you look at the OP's solution, the bottom line moves UP to the center of the div prior to the top line rotating. The OP wants the top line to move the center of the div (vertically) prior to rotating just like the other one does. Go back and look at the OPs solution. @IslamElshobokshy - this answer is not what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @RandyCasburn my bad I misunderstood!

Comment: No prob - it is an interesting problem though.

Comment: @ella I think you want the top line to move down and bottom line to move up,meeting in the middle, then make the x? is that right?

Comment: YESS @JoshAdams

Comment: @JoshAdams can u help me?

Comment: @ella i have updated for you, please leave feedback :) best of luck

Comment: I did it in another way i edited my question :)  anyways thank u very much @JoshAdams

Comment: @JoshAdams can you tell me how to add another class like active but non-active? Since i want to do another animations when i close the icon?

Comment: I'm happy to help, please post another question or we can move this to a message board, getting too many comments.